# PHP string data passed to Chart.js not rendering well

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I'm trying to work with Chart.js for the first time. I already understand how it works, but I now want to pass my data from php to javascript.

This is what I have:

PHP

```
//send the string values to javascript
$grade_range_string = mb_substr($grade_range_string, 0, -2);
$percentage_count_string = implode(", ", $percentage_count_array);
//chart colors
$grade_chart_colors_string = "";
$grade_chart_colors_array = grade_chart_colors();
foreach ($grade_chart_colors_array as $color) {
    $grade_chart_colors_string .= "'".$color."'" . ", ";
}
$grade_chart_colors_string = mb_substr($grade_chart_colors_string, 0, -2);
```

HTML

```
<span id="grade_range_string" data-value="<?php echo $grade_range_string; ?>"></span>
<span id="percentage_count_string" data-value="<?php echo $percentage_count_string; ?>"></span>
<span id="grade_chart_colors_string" data-value="<?php echo $grade_chart_colors_string; ?>"></span>

<canvas id="broadsheet_piechart"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
// Pie chart
if ( $('#broadsheet_piechart').length ) {
    var grade_range_string = $('#grade_range_string').attr('data-value');
    var percentage_count_string = $('#percentage_count_string').attr('data-value');
    var grade_chart_colors_string = $('#grade_chart_colors_string').attr('data-value');
    //debug
    console.log(grade_range_string); 
    console.log(percentage_count_string); 
    console.log(grade_chart_colors_string); 

    var ctx = document.getElementById("broadsheet_piechart");
    var data = {
        datasets: [{
            data: [percentage_count_string],
            backgroundColor: [grade_chart_colors_string],
            label: 'My dataset' // for legend
        }],
        labels: [grade_range_string]
    };
    var broadsheet_piechart = new Chart(ctx, {
        data: data,
        type: 'pie',
        options: {
            animation: {
                duration: 0
            }
        }
    });  
}
//debug
console.log(data);
```

In the console window, the 3 variables `grade_range_string`, `percentage_count_string`, `grade_chart_colors_string` return the data as formatted, but the datasets data  variable encloses the data in double quotes like this:

```
data: ["'Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item etc'"]
```

Same for `backgroundColor` and `labels`.
This ruins my pie...

Why is that happening, and how do I get rid of the quotes? Is there a better way of achieving this? Thanks.

Comment: From memory (haven't done charts.js in a while) you should be able to do: data: <?php echo json_encode($percentage_count_string); ?>,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php you can do this

```
//send the string values to javascript
$grade_range_string = mb_substr($grade_range_string, 0, -2);
$percentage_count_string = implode(", ", $percentage_count_array);
//chart colors
$grade_chart_colors_string = "";
$grade_chart_colors_array = grade_chart_colors();

// New Code
$grade_chart_colors_string = join(",", $grade_chard_colors_array); // will join all the colors with ','
//for eg. $grade_chart_colors_string = "red,blue,yellow" 


$grade_chart_colors_string = mb_substr($grade_chart_colors_string, 0, -2);
```

In javascript make the string back to an array

```
var grade_chart_colors_string = $('#grade_chart_colors_string').attr('data-value');
var grade_chart_colors_array = grade_chart_colors_string.split(',');
```

That should pass it as an array in data. You can do the rest like this

Comment: Will try this now

Answer (score 0):

You should change this:

```
<?php echo $percentage_count_string; ?>
```

to:

```
<?php echo json_encode($percentage_count_string); ?>
```

It may solve your problem

Cheers

Comment: returned nothing